# Change image dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to display images dynamically and according to their category. I have 4 buttons with the 1st I would like to display all the images and the 3 others I would like to sort them according to their categories. 
To know that an image can be in several categories.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="link">
    <a onclick="showImg()" class="link__color">All</a><!--category: 0-->
    <a onclick="showImg()" class="link__color">category-1</a>
    <a onclick="showImg()" class="link__color">category-2</a>
    <a onclick="showImg()" class="link__color">category-3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- <div class="container__img"><img class="img" src=""></div> -->
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    const partners = [
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ'`, category: [0,1,3]},
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ'`, category: [0,2]},
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGV9LR9tr0hSWJdUcD15OSk7p3X47sy4QFBB6SLOQXQYt7G8AnfA'`, category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: `src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg'`, category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'`, category: [0,2,3]},
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'`, category: [0,2]},
  {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUgwZXDhsiXxNBQ8KAxFvVcOGU0mMd8gohhRf5OP4z0NOjeO6N'`, category: [0,3]},
];


function showImg(category) {
  const createDiv = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'container__img');
  /* creatDiv = is the div that will surround every img */
  partners.forEach(function() {
    if() {

    }
  });
}
```

That's where I am after trying a lot of things. So I would like to have each image put it in my class: container__img.
And I'm not sure that forEach () is the right idea.  (Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OqCFuDExAbae8KDkfAhI?p=preview)

think it's not very complicated but for the moment I can't think of any ideas.

Comment: `{img: src="..."}`?

Comment: `forEach` is the preferred way to visit each element in an array. I would use `filter`, before the `forEach`, instead of the `if`, for readability reasons. `.filter(image => image.category.includes(category))
    .forEach(image => {...})`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce . I don't know how to add images in the js, I modified maybe it's better I don't know :(

Comment: @Aluan Haddad    I can see a little bit of what you want to do. I'm gonna try

Comment: You can put the URLs in the DOM attributes as `data-src`, then visit them in JavaScript by `element.dataset.src`.

Comment: @Nianyi Wang  In fact I really wish there was just one div in the dom no more. I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: @NianyiWang what benefit is there to that? Why bother storing them them in the DOM if they're only manipulated in JavaScript? HTML sucks for data

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry, my bad, I misunderstood the question, it should've been `data-category`, if you can get my point.

Comment: @mathiasF You're trying to store 2 different types of data (`<a>`'s & `<img>`'s) in a same container, which is logically incorrect. But there are some CSS tricks if you really wanna do that. Btw check my answer out! ;-)

Comment: @NianyiWang yes I think so. You get the correlation upfront and you don't need to map it back to the element but the downside is that your limited are the HTML syntax and your data has to be static

Comment: @AluanHaddad Idk bro, it seems that the category data is linked to DOM. It'll be **really** a pain-in-the-ass to keep them synchronized within vanilla HTML 5.

Comment: @NianyiWang yeah I don't know just discussing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your probably want to remove the `src=` parts from (the original version of) your `partners` object.
2. Your links need an `href` attribute or they won't look like links, they also need to `return false` or prevent default, they also need to include the category in the parameters..
3. Filter the array with the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.
4. Create and append each image to the container.

```js
const partners = [
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ", category: [0,1,3]},
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ", category: [0,2]},
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGV9LR9tr0hSWJdUcD15OSk7p3X47sy4QFBB6SLOQXQYt7G8AnfA", category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg", category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27", category: [0,2,3]},
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27", category: [0,2]},
  {img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUgwZXDhsiXxNBQ8KAxFvVcOGU0mMd8gohhRf5OP4z0NOjeO6N", category: [0,3]},
];


function showImg(category) {
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  const filteredImages = partners.filter(itm => ~itm.category.indexOf(category));
  filteredImages.forEach(itm => {
    const createDiv = document.createElement('div');
    createDiv.setAttribute('class', 'container__img');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      createDiv.appendChild(img);
      container.appendChild(createDiv);
    };
    img.src = itm.img
  });
  return false;
}
```

```css
.container__img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.container__img img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a href=# onclick="showImg(0)" class="link__color">All</a>
  <!--category: 0-->
  <a href=# onclick="showImg(1)" class="link__color">category-1</a>
  <a href=# onclick="showImg(2)" class="link__color">category-2</a>
  <a href=# onclick="showImg(3)" class="link__color">category-3</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- <div class="container__img"><img class="img" src=""></div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: In the `all` a tag is missing the 0 category, this should show all images

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce I didn't know that sign (~). It took me a long time to understand what I know but it's really interesting :) . thanks

Comment: @mathiasF - it turns a `-1` into a zero

Comment: I try to have the category `all` by default when I arrive on the page. I tried several solutions on the Internet but nothing works, I thought that adding `return false` to onclik was enough. But alas, it still doesn't work. If anyone has an idea?

Comment: @mathiasF ... add this to the bottom of your script... `$(()=>showImg(0));`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try, dont know if i understod you 100%

```js
const partners = [
  {img: src ="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ", category: [0,1,3]},
  {img: src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ", category: [0,2]},
  {img: src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGV9LR9tr0hSWJdUcD15OSk7p3X47sy4QFBB6SLOQXQYt7G8AnfA", category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg", category: [0,1,2]},
  {img: src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27", category: [0,2,3]},
  {img: src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27", category: [0,2]},
  {img: src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUgwZXDhsiXxNBQ8KAxFvVcOGU0mMd8gohhRf5OP4z0NOjeO6N", category: [0,3]},
];

function showImg(category) {
  const createDiv = $("#container")
  /* creatDiv = is the div that will surround every img */
  var index = $(category).index();
   $(createDiv).html(""); // clear data.
  $(partners).each(function(){
    if (this.category.find(function(v) { return v== index}) != undefined)
      $(createDiv).append($("<img style='width:50px' src='"+this.img+"' />"));
  
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">
    <a onclick="showImg(this)" class="link__color">All</a><!--category: 0-->
    <a onclick="showImg(this)" class="link__color">category-1</a>
    <a onclick="showImg(this)" class="link__color">category-2</a>
    <a onclick="showImg(this)" class="link__color">category-3</a>
  </div>

  <div id='container' class="container">
    <!-- <div class="container__img"><img class="img" src=""></div> -->
  </div>
```

Comment: WOW thanks you very much.  However, I wish I didn't have to install jquery. I will try to find something similar in pure javascript. But thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<div id="src">
    <a data-category="0">category-0</a>
    <a data-category="1">category-1</a>
    <a data-category="2">category-2</a>
    <a data-category="3">category-3</a>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>{
    const images = [
        {
            src: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ',
            category: [0, 1, 3]
        },
        {
            src: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ',
            category: [0, 2]
        },
    ],
    container = document.getElementById('container'),
    GenerateImg = src => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        return img;
    };
    document.getElementById('src').addEventListener(
        'click',
        e => {
            container.innerHTML = '';
            (
                category => images.filter(image => image.category.indexOf(category) !== -1).map(image => GenerateImg(image.src))
            )(+e.target.dataset.category).reduce((placeholder, current) => container.appendChild(current), void 0);
        }
    );
}</script>
```

Comment: you can replace the `GenerateImg` method with any DOM structures you want, say, an `<img>` wrapped with a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version (no jquery). I've tried to stick as closely to the original code design as possible.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="link">
    <a onclick="showImg(0)" class="link__color">All</a><!--category: 0-->
    <a onclick="showImg(1)" class="link__color">category-1</a>
    <a onclick="showImg(2)" class="link__color">category-2</a>
    <a onclick="showImg(3)" class="link__color">category-3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="container__img" id='container_img'><img class="img" src=""></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var partners = [
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ'", category: [0,1,3]},
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ'", category: [0,2]},
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGV9LR9tr0hSWJdUcD15OSk7p3X47sy4QFBB6SLOQXQYt7G8AnfA'", category: [0,1,2]},
{img: "src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg'", category: [0,1,2]},
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'", category: [0,2,3]},
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'", category: [0,2]},
{img: "src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUgwZXDhsiXxNBQ8KAxFvVcOGU0mMd8gohhRf5OP4z0NOjeO6N'", category: [0,3]},
];


function showImg(category) {
    var createDiv = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'container__img');
    /* creatDiv = is the div that will surround every img */
    createDiv = document.getElementById('container_img');
    createDiv.innerHTML = '';
    partners.forEach(function(partner) {
        if(partner.category.indexOf(category)!=-1) {
            createDiv.innerHTML = createDiv.innerHTML + '<img ' + partner.img + '>';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think we could do it that way. Thank you, that's the perfect answer.

Comment: However I don't understand why the .container__img css doesn't apply. If they are dynamically created I have to add the css dynamically too? Or what should the css add to #container__img?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. What css? It may be that you are confusing the name of the class (container__img) with the id of the div (container_img). The number of underscores is the difference.

Comment: In fact it's my fault I copied the code and I didn't see it but you didn't put the link to the js page.     `<script src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: And so I didn't understand why the code didn't work.

Comment: True. I didn't have that file, so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on what I think you mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="link">
        <a onclick="showImg(0)" class="link__color">All</a>
        <!-- Or:
        <a onclick="showImg([1,2,3])" class="link__color">All</a>
        -->
        <a onclick="showImg(1)" class="link__color">category-1</a>
        <a onclick="showImg(2)" class="link__color">category-2</a>
        <a onclick="showImg(3)" class="link__color">category-3</a>

        <!-- An additional example -->
        <a onclick="showImg([1,3])" class="link__color">category-1&3</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
.link__color {
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .container__img {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: red;
}

.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```
const partners = [
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTP267XEMpkNGK6SFQ97S0H417cdi3wwu6PtweMTOGSPreaJqFJWQ'`, category: [0,1,3]},
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8YvxkmxhzlS3EQ9nmwODbfDvxzdYZZCbBl_Q3mkw53qH8QIv0hQ'`, category: [0,2]},
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGV9LR9tr0hSWJdUcD15OSk7p3X47sy4QFBB6SLOQXQYt7G8AnfA'`, category: [0,1,2]},
    {img: `src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3823/11294769684_5d4b0d1a23_n.jpg'`, category: [0,1,2]},
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'`, category: [0,2,3]},
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnccHtrN6iwkll-kIreBtv9jTM831XY2-wRvtevpb8ApCtdC27'`, category: [0,2]},
    {img: `src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUgwZXDhsiXxNBQ8KAxFvVcOGU0mMd8gohhRf5OP4z0NOjeO6N'`, category: [0,3]},
];

function showImg(category) {
    category = typeof category === 'number' ? [category] : category
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    container.innerHTML = "";

    partners.forEach(image => {
        // This will compare the requested categories with the images categories
        // E.g.
        // searching for: [2]
        // image categories: [0,2,3]
        // output: [2]

        // Then check the length to see whether we can show the image
        if (image.category.filter(e => ~category.indexOf(e)).length) {
            // Image is in categories

            // Create the elements
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            const img = document.createElement('img');

            // Add the classes
            div.className = 'container__img';
            img.className = 'img';

            // add the image source
            img.src = image.img.replace(/src='([^']+)'/, "$1");

            // Append to the correct locations.
            div.appendChild(img);
            container.appendChild(div);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't think about the regex too. That's very interesting. I'll try it on.

Comment: Adding `onclick` attributes on every `<a>` seems a little redundant... You can handle them using a `forEach` or catch them in a parent click event. (I prefer event because multiple event bindings is a waste of memoy...)

Comment: Here too I don't understand why the container css is not displayed

Comment: I was trying to keep my example as close to the provided code as possible, @NianyiWang

Comment: How do you mean @mathiasF? Here is a fork of your plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/Jq8JfBO8kOhOoQBmPHKG?p=preview, the images seem to be wrapping to me?

Comment: @mathiasF, I see the issue that has arisen, your css rule is `.contain__img` where as the class you gave us was `.container__img`